# Storing a string with html in it

Tags: java, html, string, storage

I am just wondering how I can store this string to a variable without getting compile errors. Here is the code:

```
String htmldata = "<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;     charset=Utf-8"><script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.js"></script><!-- SJIS Support     (optional) --><!--<script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode_SJIS.js"></script>--><script     type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script><title name="msg">what</title></head><body    onload="update_qrcode()"><form><title>whatwhatwhat</title><input type="hidden" name="msg" value="http://www.m.com"></input></br><center><div id="qr"></div></center></form></body></html>";
```

Comment: No research effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to wrap strings in double quotes in Java. Single quotes are reserved for single characters.

**EDIT:** You'll have to escape your inner double quotes like so:

`String test = "He said \"yo\".";`

Here is your string:

```
String htmldata = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;     charset=Utf-8\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"qrcode.js\"></script><!-- SJIS Support     (optional) --><!--<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"qrcode_SJIS.js\"></script>--><script     type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"sample.js\"></script><title name=\"msg\">what</title></head><body    onload=\"update_qrcode()\"><form><title>whatwhatwhat</title><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"msg\" value=\"http://www.bjjbadges.com\"></input></br><center><div id=\"qr\"></div></center></form></body></html>";
```

Comment: Which still won't help with the embedded `"` in the HTML.

Comment: @Oded: You merely have to escape them, see my edit.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. Even when changing it to double quotes I cant figure out how to get it to be read as a string. cheers.

Comment: @jaboston: I've cleaned it up for you, you can paste it back in your editor, and observe what has been changed.

Comment: Oh right gotchya... I thought itd be something like that but wasnt sure. cheers! +1ing

Comment: @jaboston: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to use double quotes to wrap the entire string. You are also going to need to escape the " and any \ characters that are in the string.

Comment: Only full answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

Java Strings are wrapped into double quotes (`""`). If your String contains double quotes, you'll have to escape them: `"\""`

Answer (score 1):

Java String should be double quote. "..."

Comment: And what about the embedded `"` in the HTML?

Comment: @Oded easy! ask another question about what backslashes mean in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As many have mentioned above, you can use `/"`. But if u really wanna solve it in another way then replace `"` with `+(char)34+` everywhere in your HTML-code then use it.